# How to add or install plugins in grails-3.0.4 which i have used in grails-2.4.4 while upgrading application

Tags: grails, plugins, grails-plugin

1) How to add or install plugins in 3.0.4 like in 2.4.4 we can install by specifying in BuildConfig.groovy?

2) How to create new plugins and copy source code to new plugins from original plugins as documentation saying to do for up-gradation of plugins in grails-3.x?

Answer (score 3):

1. You add your plugins into the `dependencies` block in your `build.gradle`.  You find plugins [here](https://bintray.com/grails/plugins) - as stated on the plugin page.
2. Follow the instructions in the [Upgrading from Grails 2.x - Reference Documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/upgrading.html)

Comment: I have left no quotes from the linked upgrade doc, since the question is to broad and the whole document is rather large.

Comment: documentation giving some "cp -rf OldProjectPath NewProjectPath" command but when i try it giving cp command not found(relative error).

Comment: using window 7 64 bit

Comment: i'm pretty sure, there are ways to copy files in windows

Comment: This time is correct for migration to 3.0.4 or need to wait.                    Thanks cfrick for quick replys.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, migrating involves:

1. Creating a brand new Grails 3 app/plugin.
2. Copying the source from the Grails 2 project over to the new project. By source I mean controllers, domains, services, and other Grails *artefacts*, **NOT** configuration such as Config.groovy, BuildConfig.groovy, etc.
3. Reconfiguring the new project according to the changes made in Grails 3. This includes going from Config.groovy to application.yml, setting up the dependencies on Grails 3 versions of the plugins, relocating BootStrap.groovy, etc. As @cfrick mentioned, the [Upgrading from Grails 2.x - Reference Documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/upgrading.html) is your friend.
4. Fix all the compile time and runtime errors. Most likely you will have a lot of them.

An indiscriminate copy like *cp -rf OldProjectPath NewProjectPath* will not work. I recommend checking for Grails 3 versions of your plugins to see how many have been ported. That will tell you if this is the right time to migrate.