# How to install plugins in grails-3.2.0 which i have used in grails-2.4.4 while upgrading application

Tags: grails, plugins, grails-plugin, grails-3.0, grails3.2.0

I am trying to upgrade my application from Grails 2.4.4 to Grails 3.2.0. I am having problems installing plugins used in previous version. Following Questions did gave me some clarification : 
1) [First  one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31806809/how-to-add-or-install-plugins-in-grails-3-0-4-which-i-have-used-in-grails-2-4-4/31843821#31843821) 
2) [Second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32293064/how-do-i-configure-installation-of-plugins-in-grails-3-0-4)

Now I have few plugins like tomcat, jquery,etc which are not available at https://bintray.com/grails/plugins as described in [First one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31806809/how-to-add-or-install-plugins-in-grails-3-0-4-which-i-have-used-in-grails-2-4-4/31843821#31843821) question.
So can you tell me how do I add plugins which are not in this directory on plugins at bintray.

There is some problem as well I am using database-migration plugin. There is listing available at bintray and says to use it as

> compile 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.0.0'

as I added same in build.gradle file in my project under dependencies section. Project gets compiled successfully but does not run. Shows long exception but starting is as follows :

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':bootRun'.

Please help to resolve this errors while installing plugin in Grails 3.2.0

Answer (score 2):

You need an extra configuration for that plugin as [its doc says](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/3.0.x/index.html#gettingStarted).

Add in build.gradle

```
buildscript {
   dependencies {
      ...
      classpath 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.0.0'
   }
}

dependencies {
   ...
     compile 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.0.0'
}
```

It is also recommended to add a direct dependency to liquibase because Spring Boot overrides the one provided by this plugin

```
dependencies {
   ...
     compile 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.5.3'
}
```

You should also tell Gradle about the migrations folder

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir 'grails-app/migrations'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I am may have missed but could be please point out in documentation where it is stated for extra configuration?

Comment: I have added the link ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe plugins are no longer necessary and don't have direct replacements. The `tomcat` plugin is not needed because Grails 3 is built on Spring Boot and the dependency:

```
 compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
```

Provides tomcat already. The jQuery plugin is not needed either because you can simply declare a dependency on the jquery.js file directly using asset pipeline which is just as simple. See [How to Use jQuery in Grails 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042270/how-to-use-jquery-in-grails-3-0)

Comment: okay ... I may just work with that. But what about those plugins compile 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.0.0' or compile 'org.grails.plugins:cxf:3.0.14' .. how to work on them! any clues, tips or tricks, ideas?